# How to pass information using an HTTP redirect (in Django)

Tags: python, django, http

I have a view that accepts a form submission and updates a model.

After updating the model, I want to redirect to another page, and I want a message such as "Field X successfully updated" to appear on this page.

How can I "pass" this message to the other page? HttpResponseRedirect only accepts a [URL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator). I've seen this done before on other sites. How is this accomplished?

Comment: I think this problem is quite common in all frameworks and is not limited to django/python.

Comment: @Jiri, yes, but some frameworks provide support for it.

Comment: encode the message in the query string of the url you are redirecting to. should work in any framework.

Answer (score 12):

This is a built-in feature of Django, called "messages"

See http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#messages

From the documentation:

> A message is associated with a User.
>   There's no concept of expiration or
>   timestamps.
>
> Messages are used by the Django admin
>   after successful actions. For example,
>   "The poll Foo was created
>   successfully." is a message.

Comment: Doesn't this feature requires an authenticated user? Or are there anonymous/unauthenticated users supported by Django?

Comment: Doesn't require an authenticated user. The 'user' object to which the message gets attached can be an anonymous user; django creates a user object based off the session started for that visitor. Only requirement is that your visitor allow cookies.

Comment: @Jarret and @S.Lott are wrong.  Django's built-in messages are not session-based, they are database-backed and tied into actual DB user objects (the "anonymous" user does not exist in the DB), so they are only usable with authenticated users.  Try django-flashcookie or django-session-messages.

Comment: Doesn't work for anonymous users. Plus, it's been deprecated.

Comment: The trunk version(future 1.2) of Django support sending messages to anonymous users

Answer (score 8):

You can use django-flashcookie app 
http://bitbucket.org/offline/django-flashcookie/wiki/Home

it can send multiple messages and have unlimited types of messages. Lets say you want one message type for warning and one for error messages, you can write

```
def simple_action(request):
    ...
    request.flash['notice'] = 'Hello World'
    return HttpResponseRedirect("/")
```

or

```
def simple_action(request):
    ...
    request.flash['error'] = 'something wrong'
    return HttpResponseRedirect("/")
```

or

```
def simple_action(request):
    ...
    request.flash['notice'] = 'Hello World'
    request.flash['error'] = 'something wrong'
    return HttpResponseRedirect("/")
```

or even

```
def simple_action(request):
    ...
    request.flash['notice'] = 'Hello World'
    request.flash['notice'] = 'Hello World 2'
    request.flash['error'] = 'something wrong'
    request.flash['error'] = 'something wrong 2'
    return HttpResponseRedirect("/")
```

and then in you template show it with

```
{% for message in flash.notice %}
    {{ message }}
{% endfor }}
```

or

```
{% for message in flash.notice %}
    {{ message }}
{% endfor }}
{% for message in flash.error %}
    {{ message }}
{% endfor }}
```

Answer (score 5):

I liked the idea of using the message framework, but the example in the django documentation doesn't work for me in the context of the question above.

What really annoys me, is the line in the django docs:

`If you're using the context processor, your template should be rendered with a RequestContext. Otherwise, ensure messages is available to the template context.`

which is incomprehensible to a newbie (like me) and needs to expanded upon, preferably with what those 2 options look like.

I was only able to find solutions that required rendering with RequestContext... which doesn't answer the question above.

I believe I've created a solution for the 2nd option below:

Hopefully this will help someone else.

== urls.py ==

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from views import *

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^$', main_page, { 'template_name': 'main_page.html', }, 'main_page'),
    (r'^test/$', test ),
```

== viewtest.py ==

```
from django.contrib import messages
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

def test(request):
    messages.success( request, 'Test successful' )
    return HttpResponseRedirect( reverse('main_page') )
```

== viewmain.py ==

```
from django.contrib.messages import get_messages
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response

def main_page(request, template_name ):
    # create dictionary of items to be passed to the template
    c = { messages': get_messages( request ) }

    # render page
    return render_to_response( template_name, c, )
```

== main_page.html ==

```
{% block content %}
    {% if messages %}
    <div>
        {% for message in messages %}
            <h2 class="{{message.tag}}">{{ message.message }}</h2>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 4):

I have read and checked all answers, and it seems to me that the way to go now is using [the messaging framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/contrib/messages/). Some of the replies are fairly old and have probably been the right way at the time of the posting.

Answer (score 3):

There is a lot of solutions

1 Use Django-trunk version - it support sending messages to Anonymous Users

2 Sessions

```
def view1(request):
    request.session['message'] = 'Hello view2!'
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/view2/')


def view2(request):
    return HttpResponse(request.session['message'])
```

3 redirect with param

```
return HttpResponseRedirect('/view2/?message=Hello+view2')
```

4 Cookies

Answer (score 1):

Can you just pass the message as a query param oon the URL to which you're redirecting?  It's not terribly RESTy, but it ought to work:

```
return HttpResponseRedirect('/polls/%s/results/?message=Updated" % p.id)
```

and have that view check for a message param, scrub it for nasties, and display it at the top.

Answer (score 1):

I think this code should work for you

```
request.user.message_set.create(message="This is some message")
return http.HttpResponseRedirect('/url')
```

Answer (score 0):

While all suggestions so far work, I would suggest going with Ry4an's (pass it in the request URL) - just change the actual text to a coded text within a predefined set of text messages.

Two advantages here:

1. Less chance of something hacking through your scrubbing of bad content
2. You can localize your messages later if needed.

The other cookie related methods.. well, they don't work if the browser doesn't support cookies, and are slightly more expensive.. But only slightly. They're indeed cleaner to the eye.

Comment: I really don't like the idea of passing user messages via URL - it just destroys the cleanliness of Django

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Django's messages framework. http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/messages/#ref-contrib-messages

Answer (score 0):

You could also have the redirect url be the path to an already parameterized view.

urls.py:

```
(r'^some/path/(?P<field_name>\w+)/$', direct_to_template,
    {'template': 'field_updated_message.html',
    },
    'url-name'
),
```

views.py:

```
HttpResponseRedirect( reverse('url-name', args=(myfieldname,)) )
```

Note that args= needs to take a tuple.

Answer (score 0):

The solution used by Pydev UA is the less intrusive and can be used without modifying almost nothing in your code. When you pass the message, you can update your context in the view that handles the message and in your template you can show it.

I used the same approach, but instead passing a simple text, passed a dict with the information in useful fields for me. Then in the view, updated context as well and then returned the rendered template with the updated context.

Simple, effective and very unobstrusive.