# Pass errors in Django using HttpResponseRedirect

Tags: python, django, django-sessions

I know that HttpResponseRedirect only takes one parameter, a URL.  But there are cases when I want to redirect with an error message to display.

I was reading this post: [How to pass information using an HTTP redirect (in Django)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/599280/how-to-pass-information-using-an-http-redirect-in-django) and there were a lot of good suggestions.  I don't really want to use a library that I don't know how works.  I don't want to rely on messages which, according to the Django docs, is going to be removed.  I thought about using sessions.  I also like the idea of passing it in a URL, something like:

```
return HttpResponseRedirect('/someurl/?error=1')
```

and then having some map from error code to message.  Is it good practice to have a global map-like structure which hard codes in these error messages or is there a better way?

Or should I just use a session

EDIT:  I got it working using a session.  Is that a good practice to put things like this in the session?

Comment: Have you read about the messages framework yet?  If not, why not?

Comment: As I said, I'm not sure I want to put something into a web application that's deprecated and will be removed.  According to the Django docs "Deprecated in Django 1.2: The Messages component of the auth system will be removed in Django 1.4."

Comment: "The Messages component of the auth system" is unrelated to the messages framework.  Completely unrelated.  Please do not confuse the two at all.  Please actually read about the messages framework.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are right about the auth messages. They are deprecated but as the [docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#messages) suggest you should use the [django messages framework](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/messages/) instead, which I think is the exact soultion for your case.

Comment: I read the messages page.  That does look promising.  It seems that the messaging framework can be set to store the data in the session.  One thing I don't quite understand, one of the parameters is the request.  I would call messages.error(request, 'Email box full') for example, and then pass messages to the template.  However, when I have a HttpResponseRedirect, I have a new request.  Is my message still accessible in the new view?

Comment: yeah it is.....the messages are stored in the session till they are accessed somewhere.

Comment: @JPC: "is my message still accessible in the new view?"  The first (#1, lead-off, initial) sentence is this: "Django provides full support for cookie- and session-based messaging".  Please actually read the documentation.  That seems clear.  What part about it confused you?

Comment: I guess because I haven't tried it out yet its a little confusing, I'll try and add some code